# How to make the results form what i want

Tags: equation-solving, variable

I have a question that method to make the result form what i want.

```
equation =2 Integrate[-(L^3 h^2 (-2R1+L p0 h))/(2H),{h,0,1/2}] + (p0 L - 2 R1)/k (-2)
```

The result is

[image]

I want to make the result form as

[image]

Is it possible in Mathematica?

and how to i get

[image]

my code is

```
sol1 = Solve[(equation == 0) /. {R1/(p0 L) -> a, (k L^3)/H -> kk}, a]
```

but it is not work.

Plesas tell me the method if these can be possible in Mathematica

Comment: Your replacement list doesn't do anything, there are no elements of the forms `R1/(p0 L)` and `(k L^3)/H`

Comment: Why do you want *Mathematica* to solve it in a specific form?

Comment: To simplify through substitution. If it can not possible, i will delete my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining $x = kL^3/H$ and $y = R/(p_0 L)$ and solve for $y$?

```
equation = 
  2 Integrate[-(L^3 h^2 (-2 R1 + L p0 h))/(2 H), {h, 0, 
      1/2}] + (p0 L - 2 R1)/k (-2);
rep = {k -> x*H/L^3, R1 -> y*p0*L};
Solve[(equation /. rep // Simplify) == 0, y]
```

> {{y -> (3 (128 + x))/(16 (48 + x))}}

Comment: What a nice idea!. Thank you